# Postman API - Variable generating but not passing as expected

Tags: javascript, testing, postman

I'm new to using postman to create tests for a simple api. As part of this I want to create a post request, then use the generated id in subsequent Get, Put and Delete tests. Below is how I'm saving the id as a variable (have also saved it in the environment) and my API schema.

```js
pm.test("Status code is 201", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(201);
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.environment.set('todo2', jsonData.id)
});
```

```js
{
        "id": "integer",
        "name": "string",
        "isComplete": boolean
    },
```

But when I try to call my Get request for that generated id using {{todo2}} in my header it instead returns everything from my API rather than the specific api which I thought I had saved in the variable. Can anyone help point me in the right direction, not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem! I was updating my environmental variables and trying to call global variables, so I was getting an undefined.

Solved by changing my code to the below and making sure I had declared my variables via the global environment menu on the top right.

```
 pm.test("Status code is 201", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(201);
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.globals.set('todo2', jsonData.id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you json is valid?

```
{
    "id": "integer",
    "name": "string",
    "isComplete": "boolean"
}
```

you need double quotes for `boolean` value, because this is a string there.

Comment: Made the change, still getting everything returned on my get request rather than the specific that I'm specifying using the variable in the header.

One issue solved though, thanks!